# Cant sorting after array_filter in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, directory, glob

I want to get all Folders name. I'm using following codes for that. In main Folder some other files also there. I want to sort the folders name in 'ASC' order.

I can't do by following functions,

```
<?php
  $dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
  sort($dirs); //used asort() and array_multisort()
  print_r($dirs);
?>
```

> It's giving priority to CAPS Letters

I'm getting, Arranging first which folder name starting with CAPS. After that others...

Help me, Thanks...

Comment: So what do you get and what do you expect instead?

Comment: *Note: It's giving priority to CAPS Letters* -> [Understand ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: It's giving priority to CAPS Letters

If that means you want to sort case-insensitively, then you need to set the appropriate flag:

```
sort($dirs, SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Or use another sorting function:

```
natcasesort($dirs);
```

Or use manual comparison with a case-insensitive function:

```
usort($dirs, 'strcasecmp');
```

See the [comparison of array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and their relevant individual manual pages.